# Traveling in the Philippines after Haiyan (Feb 2014)

Tags: safety, philippines

[Typhoon Haiyan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typhoon_Haiyan) devastated portions of the Philippines in November 2013.

What are current practical effects of that? Are there areas which should be avoided by a backpack traveler? I'm willing to sacrifice comfort, but not safety and the availability of (public) transport and accommodation.

I am going to travel to the Philippines in February and am currently looking for possible itineraries.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is **none**.  The brunt of Haiyan's impact was on the islands of Leyte and Samar, neither of which is really a tourist destination.  Cebu, which is, only sustained relatively minor damage, and places outside the Visayas like Manila and Palawan came through virtually unscathed.

Comment: Agreed, although I had heard that Palawan was hit pretty hard -- although I'm reasonably sure it wouldn't be a problem to visit there now.